# Find appropriate task manager host address for queryable state

Tags: apache-flink

I have 4 task managers and using map state backend(RocksDB) . 
using QueryableStateClient to query the state . 
1.How to get correct task manager to query the state instead of querying all the task manager . (KvstateLocation ) can someone provide sample code unable to find it in the doc.

2. How do we get jobid hex string using job name .

Flink 1.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Find the task manager to query state

In fact, you can query any task manager. Because the task manager will help you route the key to the correct task manager through a lookupTable from job manager.

> How do we get jobid hex string using job name

Flink provides API (/jobs/overview) to get job information.